# Is the Editability of Proposals Potentially Harmful to the Democratic Process?

Tags: discussion, edits

This is my very first "question" on **any** SE site. *YAY!*

I was over at Area 51 looking through the Example Questions for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) when I came across [this example](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review/11485#11485/) by Larry Smithmier. Comments by DarkLight and Felix (as well as Larry himself) seem to suggest that Larry had changed the question at some point — resulting in 2 votes for "great on-topic example" (probably unintentionally) — then changed it back.

Now, this discussion isn't about Larry, Code Review, or Area 51 for that matter. It's about the underlying system. I'm of the opinion that *any proposal* that's *up for vote* **should not be editable** OR that any changes made should be clearly visible as amendments to the original proposal.

Please understand that I'm not suggesting Larry did anything wrong — intentionally or otherwise, nor that this is a “stack-wide problem of epic proportion”. However, one can clearly see how the *ability* to edit a proposal which is up for vote could *potentially* lead to abuse.

I’m admittedly quite new to SE and perhaps this "glitch" is unique to Area 51, but it bothered me (from a democratic standpoint) so I thought I’d elicit your thoughts on the matter.

Happy Stacking and may the Skeet be with you. :)

Comment: How is this different from editing real questions or answers on the actual Q&A sites after they have been voted on?

Comment: Because (in the case of example questions) it determines whether or not a new SE site makes it to beta. I haven't had the opportunity to vote for mods yet, but I hope the voting system is more sound than this example.

Comment: Is it just me, or has the shadow under avatars grown since 8am?

Comment: How is this related to democracy in any way? It's cheating at worst, and at best a misunderstanding. (*Yes, I always start to get itchy if people are throwing such buzzwords around.*)

Comment: @Straitjacket Voting is a democratic act. Buzzword or not, that's what it is.

Comment: Off topic, but how come my avatar doesn't do that cool pop out thing when I hover over it?

Comment: Because you don't have 1000 rep. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104113/user-info-popup-how-does-it-work/104171#104171

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I see it, this is a totally made-up problem.

- You give *one* example that resulted in *two* on-topic votes (as supposed to *twenty* off-topic votes).
- You say in your comment that this has an implication on "whether or not a new SE site makes it to beta." It certainly didn't in this case. The proposol *is* in beta (with your example being in the Top Example Questions list), and the existence or non-existence of those two votes would have made no difference in this.
- If someone *actually* (not just theoretically) used this to game the system: Believe it or not, there are still people looking at these example questions: users like you, the community moderation team, etc. If someone asks "My gold fish is getting fat, should I feed it diet food?" on the Animal Food proposal, gets twenty on topic votes, and then the question is edited to be "How is babby formed", do you really think this would go by unnoticed?
- Once a proposal enters the commitment phase, the questions are locked and *can't* be edited any more.

As I said in my comment, this is no different then allowing editing of real questions and answers on the actual Q&A sites after they have been voted on.

Comment: I implied it "could" be a "potential" problem. I didn't make it up at all. The example I gave was to introduce my topic. It's also what got me thinking about it. I was under the impression that meta is where we discuss things about SE (improvements, problems, etc.) Are you saying that we can't discuss the theoretical?

Comment: "Once a proposal enters the commitment phase, the questions are locked and can't be edited any more." That was actually helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The last two bullet points are valid and acceptable answers. The first two miss the point of my post by focusing on an example, which I clearly stated was not the subject of my post. Besides, I never said it _is_ a problem. I was concerned it might _become_ a problem. Is it necessary to berate me for caring?